# OAuthException 3502 even when posting correct object type to facebook graph

Tags: facebook, exception, facebook-graph-api, oauth, facebook-opengraph

I've read several posts where people specify the wrong og:type or og:url in their object instances, and that produces this error.  This is a different situation.

I have one app which works perfectly. It defines action 'love', which works on object 'item', and it produces e.g. 'Joe loves music' just fine. Its app namespace is 'promo'.

For testing purposes, I've created a 2nd app, nearly identical, with the same action and object definitions.  Because apps cannot use the same namespace, I've assigned this app's namespace to 'promoTest'. And I've made my code configurable so that objects produced by this 2nd app will appear as the correct og:type = promoTest:item.

So to summarize

- app 1 produces objects of og:type 'promo:item'
- app 2 produces objects of og:type 'promoTest:item'.
- Both type prefixes match their app's respective namespaces.
- Objects produced from both of these apps work fine in the object debugger. 0 errors.

The problem is, app 1 works perfectly, while app 2 produces the following error:

```
OAuthException: (#3502) Object at URL <url> has og:type of 'promoTest:item'. The property 'item' requires an object of og:type 'promo:item'.
```

App 2 is producing the correct type. But facebook is complaining it wants the type that is associated with App 1. It's almost as if app 1's item is superceding app 2's item. Surely there are hundreds of apps with objects named 'item', which is why we need namespaces.

So why is facebook asking app 2 for app 1's namespace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things possibly wrong here:

- The fb:app_id tag must match the app you're trying to use
- The URLs of the two objects must be different - for example, you should have app1.example.com/some/url and app2.example.com/some/url - otherwise Facebook will see the same URL and will see it as related to whichever app was being used when an action was first posted against it.